# Oracle data migrating within different schemas

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-migration

In my Oracle 11 database I have two schemas with slightly different datamodels (target schema is empty also column and table names are in a different language)

I want to migrate data from one to another. I have around 15 tables, So the column and table names, needs to be mapped within each other, some tables needs to be merged into 1 new table in target schema etc and then migrate data.

Do I have to do this manually with scripts, or there is some help I can get from Oracle SqlDeveloper? or anything else to help mapping?

Comment: You'll have to define the mapping somewhere, so with only 15 tables I'd have thought it would be easy enough to do manually. Is this related to your earlier question about writing to a file and then using SQL*Loader? This sounds like two schema in the same DB, but I might be wrong; if that is the case you could probably make your life easier by just selecting from the other schema, without an intermediate file?

Comment: @Alex Poole yes I managed to migrate from mysql to oracle but with "same" data modal, now next step is to tweak and make it look like the target schema..what do you mean by selecting from other schema ?

Comment: Like... `insert into schema2.new_table(col1, col2, ...) select col1, col2, ... from schema1.old_table`. The schemas (users) need to be able to see each other's data though - at least `schema2` needs to be able to select from `schema1`'s tables. Whatever manipulation you need to do on the data (merging etc.) can be done in the `select`.

Comment: @Alex Poole how can I give that right? they r in same database I thought by default they can access

Comment: @Alex Poole there are 2 tables in old schema needs to be merged into 1 table thats what makes me worry..

Comment: While logged in as `schema1`, do `grant select on old_table to schema2`. Then `schema2` will be able to select from that table. If you're merging data from two table into one you can just do a join - if you can write a query to select the data in the combination you need it, you can use that same `select` as part of an `insert`. I think that's suitable for you but it's hard to tell with so little information.

Comment: @Alex Poole I can give more information if you like :)

Answer (score 2):

Since table and column names need to be mapped, this surely must involve some manual work. Personally I would just use plain SQL to map the structure and copy data, as you were already suggested, especially if target database is empty - so it's just a simple insert.

If you want a tool for this, you can try dbForge Data Compare. I haven't used it, so I can't say for sure, but on the [features page](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/datacompare/features.html) it states that:

- User mapping feature allows comparing tables with different names and column set
- Map one table in source with two or more tables in target (useful when table was split)

so maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It will involve some manual work, either through comparing two repositories with a home brewn script or a good CASE tool.

Or use Dell's TOAD. The DBA option of TOAD allows you to compare two schemas and generates scripts which change schema 1's structure into schema 2's structure (or otherwise around). See [TOAD documentation](http://documents.software.dell.com/DOC127947)

When it is one time exercise, I would use TOAD to generate the SQL and manually adapt it where necessary.

When it is a recurring problem, you might want to develop your own scripts or purchase a good starting point.